# Checking records consistency after mongorestore --noobjcheck

Tags: mongodb, nosql, corruption

I had an HDD malfunction on a Mongo node.  After running `fsck` and `mongod --repair` I was able to dump the needed collection with `mongodump` and move it to another server.

However, some records appear to be malformed and `mongorestore` fails with:

> assertion: 10331 EOO Before end of object

I restored the collection with `mongorestore --noobjcheck` and now I want to remove the malformed records from the collection.

How do I do that?  Is there a way to force Mongo to check itself or must I do it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a --repairDatabase for that node:

```
mongod --repair --repairpath <repair_path>
```

Keep in mind that the repair path should have at least as your data size free disk space. (if you have 100GB, the repair path should have at least 100GB free also.
That should take care of problems of that sort.

Also, in the future if anything of some sort happen again and you need to run mongodump,
 you can run the `mongodump --repair.`
This will ensure that any corrupted data will not be dumped.

Hope this helps